# Is there any way to disable the autobuffering and/or automatic loading of YouTube videos whenever I load a page?

Tags: web-apps, chrome, youtube, flash, connection-speed

I've checked all the YouTube and Chrome settings but there isn't any option available to disable flash player. Also, I've tried an add-on (Chrome) named Flashcontrol but it too is inefficient for this purpose.

If it isn't possible then is there any way through which I can set speed limit of a particular website.

Finally, if there isn't any possibility of any of these options then is there any other browser that can support this functionality?

Comment: Could you please detail what exactly is the problem with Flashcontrol? Thanks!

Comment: Flashcontrol at YT just doesn't work as if it was not present at all.

Comment: Are you sure that you use Flash to play YT videos? I think that HTML5 is the default nowadays.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. I use latest version of Chrome and Adobe Flash player. Flashcontrol do block some type of videos on a few sites but not on YT.

Comment: You can check here (https://www.youtube.com/html5) if you are using HTML5 or Flash on YT. As you are using the newest Chrome version it is probable that YT is not using Flash but HTML5 to play the videos. That would also be the reason why Flashcontrol is not blocking the videos on YT.

If you are using Flash, then I am not sure if it is better to create a new question or edit this question. Nicolas Raoul, any advice?

Comment: Thankyou so much @gillesB for this link.
Unfortunately I can't uncheck HTML5 option there.

Comment: The page is only to check if HTML5 will be used. You can try the following link http://codegena.com/disable-youtube-html5-player-and-load-flash/ . If you have further problems with this topic, I think it is better to open another question, as we become quite chatty.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers come with a build-in Click-To-Play functionality for plugins. With this functionality you can selectively choose if Flash (or other plugins) should be enabled on a website. To enable it there is no external plug-in needed, you can find it in the settings of your browser.

Newer version of Chrome have enabled it by default for Flash. If it is not the case you can find it in the preference page:

- Preferences/Settings
- Show Advanced Settings
- Privacy
- Content settings
- Flash

There choose "Ask before Websites can execute Flash (recommended)" (the wording may differ).

Comment: Thanks! This solution only works if you have configured YouTube to use Flash rather than HTML5, I guess?

Comment: Yes, exactly this is of course a downside. But the question was explicitly about Flash. So in hindsight the question is perhaps a bit confusing because HTML5 is the technology which needs to be blocked. But I think only ankit can clarify that.